# What does emphasized dired file permission mean?

Tags: dired

For example, below we see a website directory, and that the write permission for group is emphasized (in orange):

[image]

No emphasis when the group of the file doesn't have write permission, for example, the parent directory `..`

What does the emphasis indicate? Does it indicate insecure configuration? a warning? or something else? Should I worry?

Comment: Not sure what it means, but you might try `C-u C-x =` with point on one of those `w`s, in the buffer that pops up there should be the `face` used listed near the bottom which might give a hint as to what it means.

Comment: @npostavs I tryed it, and the documentation says "Face used to highlight permissions of group- and world-writable files.", so... it is just exactly what it seems to be, it must be a way of warning possibly insecure permissions, but in my case (for example) I know why I set permissions this way, so I am fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w` is highlighted for others than yourself only to *make sure you notice it*, as it was deemed important to bring to your attention (more important than highlighting the other permissions or `w` for yourself).

The face used is called `dired-perm-write`, and its doc string tells you:

> Face used to highlight permissions of group- and world-writable files.

I proposed to Emacs dev what [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) offers, which is (by default) to color *each* permission (`r`, `w, etc.) differently.  That was rejected, but they at least agreed to highlighting`w`.

Vanilla Emacs was quite conservative about highlighting stuff (it still is, but less so).